# Hive SQL: How to join number to a string of delimited numbers

Tags: sql, hive

I need to join two tables by an ID where one ID is stored as a number (i.e. 12345) the other ID is stored as a pipe delimited string (i.e 12345|12346|12347).  Is there a quick way to join on the two?  Thanks!

** I guess I should say join if the number ID (12345) is in the string of numbers (12345|12346|12347).  In theory this example would join as 12345 is in the pipe delimited string.

Comment: I'm not sure about quick.  If it were comma delimited, `FIND_IN_SET` would work nicely.  Perhaps you can replace the pipes with commas and then find.

Answer (score 1):

This will work in Hive

```
select obj1.*,obj2.some_fields from table1 obj1 
JOIN table2 obj2 
on (obj1.id=split(obj2.id,'|')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me if you mean SQL or HiveQL.

> Is there a quick way to join on the two?

No, not really.

Your DB schema violates First Normal Form. Joining these tables will be slow and error prone.

For DB-agnostic try:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON  t2.id LIKE ('%' + CAST(t1.id as varchar) + '%')
```

Comment: It is HiveQL.  The "table" with the pipe delimited string will actually be coming from an external file.  I just tried to keep the question as simple as possible.